# Make Laravel API only accessible from frontend (no direct access)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api

My simple web application consists of a Laravel API as backend and a React App as frontend. The application is accessible through *https://example.com* and makes requests to *https://api.example.com*. Therefore only requests from the frontend should be allowed.

So, I have already updated the CORS configuration in `config/cors.php` of the backend like this:

```php
'allowed_origins' => ['https://example.com'],
```

However, this does not restrict direct access to the API through *https://api.example.com*, which is unfortunately still possible.

Is there a way to do both, restricting direct access and allowing requests only from the frontend?

Comment: I think there is no way, as your "front" end is always the person PC, so there is really not "unique" access (single access from one part of the internet)... Remember front-end is JS, so it is running on the client's PC, so it is going to be their IP, machine, etc.

Comment: No it's not possible. If a browser can access it then a person pretending to be a browser can also access it. That's just how it is

Comment: Can you show us routes in both sides, api and frontend?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to resolve, but I think that you need, is only a specific URL to be accessible to your API?

Comment: My other question it's you want to limit the access to API via WEB request?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add a custom global http header, to the requests made from the react app to the backend.

For eg: In axios you can set custom global header

```js
axios.defaults.headers.common['x-spa-custom'] = 'my-custom-value';
```

To make it a bit more complex you could also do (Option 2)

```js
function base64encode(input: string): string {
  return Buffer.from(input).toString('base64');
}

//Value for the custom header can be based on the url and time of request like

const customHeaderValue = base64encode(
    JSON.stringify({url:location.href, tor:new Date().getTime()})
)

//And then use this value in custom header
axios.defaults.headers.common['x-spa-custom'] = customHeaderValue;
```

Then in the Laravel backend, you may define a middleware to check for the presence of custom header

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;



class EnsureIsFromSpa extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Check if the incoming request is from react frontend.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function handle($request, $next)
    {
        if ($request->hasHeader('x-spa-custom') && $request->header === 'my-custom-value') {
            return $next($request);
        }

        /**
         * If using Option 2 (above) 
         * if($request->hasHeader('x-spa-custom') {
         *     $headerValue = json_decode(
         *         base64_decode($request->header('x-spa-custom')),
         *         true
         *     );
         * Compare the value against something or atleast check the difference between tor and current timestamp
         * }
         */

        //Can even throw a custom exception here and handle via the App\Exceptions\Handler
        //Or redirect to home page
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Then you can apply `EnsureIsFromSpa` to the routes which you want to protect (kind of) from access other than react frontend.

Note: This isn't a robust solution which can't be circumvented, Making requests via Postman or curl people can still add the header and access the "protected" pages if they figure out the missing custom header.

**Caution:** The above is intended only to make it difficult for direct access to certain **GET** routes like for example `/api/users?role=admin` which do not allow any manipulation to the database however returns data in something like `json` format for consumption in a javascript frontend framework.

Routes which allow for any kind of **destructive data manipulation** like updating or deleting records or display sensitive personal information (kind of like for your eyes only of a logged in user) **should always be protected behind a robust authentication and authorisation system**.

Laravel offers multiple first part packages related to authentication:

[Laravel Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze)

[Laravel Fortify](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify)

[Laravel Jetstream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/)

[Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport)

[Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum)

[Laravel Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/socialite)

Answer (score 1):

You can lock down your API and grant access to your frontend via Laravel Sanctum's "[API Token Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#api-token-authentication)".

Comment: The Laravel Documentation says explicitly that *you should not use API tokens to authenticate your own first-party SPA. Instead, use Sanctum's built-in SPA authentication features.* I implemented it as mentioned in the documentation. Unfortunately I can still access the API endpoint directly from the browser and make requests to it.

Comment: Do your routes have the `auth:sanctum` middleware attached?

Comment: @RichardBowen What if certain api endpoints are used to fetch data via **GET** requests to populate public facing (web) pages. Those api endpoints can't be locked away under sanctum. However one may also want these routes, normally returning json data for consumption in javascript frontend framework, to not be easily accessible directly.

Comment: @RichardBowen when I attached the `auth:sanctum` middleware to all routes, I have been redirected to /login for all requests. Since there is no user authentication, that's not what I wanted.